# Not sure what is happening to tomato plant

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, fungus

Not sure what is happening to my tomato plant. Plants have been in a really sunny spot. We had been in a drought, but we’re consistently watering. Then the last few days it started raining pretty heavy all day.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like too much water, or a deficiency..try some *chelated iron* and/or some epsom salt *magnesium sulfate* even a "miracle grow type" fertilizer can help the issue some, but will take more applications to get the results you want but i wouldn't do so until next water cycle, or in the heat of the day..a good indicator of when to water tomatoes is when they ever so slightly start to wilt, or just buy a moisture meter and check it every day.. they can be sensitive to over watering and even rain can cause that

Answer (score 0):

The structure looks good, maybe the roots have remained too wet from the rain: even if theres 2 or 3 cm of gravel under the soil for drainage & aereation, the soil many have compacted around it from the rain  resulting in inadequate drainage & aereation. And if applying a granular type of nutrient, there might be excessive nutrient dissolved too rapidly by all the rain and overwhelming it.

If its waterlogged roots, then alleviating that could help!

Comment: Thank you. I was worried it could be blight.